# possible plugin for not allowing certain user roles to login until payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, user-roles

Wanted to inquire if there is any certain plugin available that restricts certain user roles to signin unless they have paid for the subscription .

if their subscription fee is cleared then they are allowed to login otherwise not. The prefered payment method is PayPal

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could not find any wordpress plugin.. so have done manually in another way .. (The user is allowed to login but is not promoted until they have made the payment..